# Finding inverse of a function $h(x) = \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

I have a function:

$$h(x) = \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}$$

With just pen and paper, how can I determine if there exists an inverse function? Am I supposed to sketch it on paper to see if it can have an invers? Or is there another/simplier way to do it?

How would I go about solving it? This is what I did:
$$h(x) = \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}} = y$$
$$y(1 + \sqrt{x}) = 1-\sqrt{x}$$
$$y + y\sqrt{x} = 1-\sqrt{x}$$
$$\text{Cancel out roots:}$$
$$y^2 + y^2x = 1+x$$
$$y^2 + y^2x - x = 1$$
$$y^2 + x(y^2 - 1) = 1$$
$$x(y^2 - 1) = 1 - y^2$$
$$x = \frac{1 - y^2}{y^2 - 1}$$
$$\text{Swap x and y and we get the inverse function:}$$
$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1 - x^2}{x^2 - 1}$$
$$\text{But the correct answer is supposed to be:}$$
$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{(1 - x)^2}{(1 + x)^2},  -1< x \le 1$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly did you do when you 'canceled out' roots?

Comment: $\dfrac{1 - x^2}{x^2 - 1}=-1$ if $x \not= \pm1$ should be a clue to a problem

Comment: @GitGud I raised everything to the power of 2

Comment: @lawls I see. Your mistake is thinking that $\forall a,b\in \mathbb R\left((a-b)^2=a^2+b^2\right)$.

Comment: @GitGud True, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice work!
But this is how you should have done it!
$$\begin{align}1-y&=y\sqrt x+\sqrt x\\
1-y&=(y+1) \sqrt x\\
\frac{1-y}{y+1}&=\sqrt x\\
\sqrt x&=\frac{1-y}{y+1}\\
x&=\frac{(1-y)^2}{(y+1)^2}\\
\end{align} $$
Hence $f^{-1}(x)$
$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{(1 - x)^2}{(x+ 1)^2}$$

Comment: Thank you! I see my mistake now. What would I need to do to determine the functions domain?

Answer (score 5):

It is important to remember that
$$(A+B)^2=A^2+\mathbf{2AB}+B^2$$

This what I'd do:
$$y(1+\sqrt x)=1-\sqrt x$$
$$y+y\sqrt x=1-\sqrt x$$
$$(y+1)\sqrt x=1-y$$
$$(y+1)^2x=(1-y)^2$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 4):

*Alternative answer*: as you are only asking if the function has an inverse, you can compute $f'(x)$ (in fact calculating $\tfrac{d}{dx}(\tfrac{1-x}{1+x} = 1-\tfrac{2}{x+1})$ is enough) and notice that $f'<0$.

So $f$ is strictly decreasing and, hence, injective. Therefore, $f$ has an inverse.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably conceptually the simplest method.

For $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$, we always have $\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{c+d}{c-d}$, provided that $a-b\not=0$ and $c-d\not=0$.

$$y = \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}$$

$$\frac{y}{1} = \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}$$

$$\frac{y+1}{y-1} = \frac{1-\sqrt{x}+(1+\sqrt{x})}{1-\sqrt{x}-(1+\sqrt{x})}=\frac{2}{-2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{-\sqrt{x}}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1}=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$$
$$x=\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2}$$

So
$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{(1 - x)^2}{(1+x)^2}$$